# Wronskian of two solutions to a second-order ODE is zero $\implies$ linearly dependent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I show that If the Wronskian of two solutions to a second-order ODE with $\textbf{no boundary conditions}$ is zero then they are linearly dependent?

Please do not mark this as duplicate as there is no answer to this particular question nowhere.

Comment: That answer is wrong. Consider $f_1=x^2$ and $f_2=x|x|$. They have zero Wronskian, but are independent

Comment: It was the wrong link, sorry for that. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/437750/669687.

Comment: There they only state what I am asking

Comment: $f_2=x|x|$ is not twice continuously differentiable and can thus not be a solution of a second order ODE. With any higher power you get that value and derivative at zero are zero, so still not a solution of a second order ODE whose domain includes $x=0$.