# Does vanishing of wronskian of solutions at point $\implies$ solutions are linearly dependent?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

> Let $u$ and $v$ be two  solutions of  $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$,Let $W(u,v)$ denote the wronskian of $u$ and $v$ then $W(u,v)$ vanishes at a point $x_0\in[a,b]\implies u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent

$W(u,v)(x_0)=0 $ for some $x_0\in [a,b]
\implies W(x)=0~,~~ \forall x\implies W(x)$ is identically zero on $[a,b]\implies u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent

**Where I'm commiting mistake?**

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Proof that ODE solutions with Wronskian identically zero are linearly dependent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143686/proof-that-ode-solutions-with-wronskian-identically-zero-are-linearly-dependent?rq=1).

Comment: @user539887:It is not duplicate of this,my intention is two about  the fuctions whose wronskian is zero at any particular point of the domain but the functions are LI?Read warning just before example 2 here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Wronskian.aspx

Comment: For *any* two functions it can happen that their Wronskian is constantly equal to zero but they are linearly independent (see my remark below Emilio Novati's answer).  But this is impossible for solutions of a linear homogeneous second order ODE.

Comment: For a solution system of a linear ODE, the difference in Wronskian values is an exponential of some regular continuous function. Thus zero in one point implies zero in every point. Linear dependence can be shown more directly using a kernel vector of the Wronski matrix, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768011/wronskian-zero-and-linear-dependence/2768865#2768865, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3467219/any-two-solution-of-the-equation-ypxyqxy-0-px-and-qx-are-con/3469725#3469725

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The theorem is:

> If the Wronskian $W(u,v)(x_0)$  is **nonzero** for *some* $x_0 \in [a,b]$ then $u$ and $v$ are linearly *independent* on $[a,b]$.

The contraposition is:

> If $u$ and $v$ are linearly *dependent* then the Wronskian is **zero** *for all* $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: :The theorem says that if wronskian is nonzero at some point of the domain of Differential equation the solutions are Linearly independent.It does not say anything about the case if wronskian is zero at some point.Right??Can you give me an example of two linearly independent functions whose wronskian is zero at some particular point of the domain??

Comment: @PKStyles See, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428204/calculate-the-wronskian-of-ft-tt-and-gt-t2-on-the-following-intervals), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429995/question-about-linear-dependence-and-independence-by-using-wronskian).

Comment: The point here is that when we say that a linear combination of two functions $\alpha u + \beta v=0$ for $\alpha, \beta$ not zerol ( i.e. the functions are linearly dependent), the $0$ at RHS is the **zero function of the vector space**, i.e. the function that is null fon any value in the domain.